# autoware open planner

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have only one point cloud map in autoware，Can I do global path planning by using op_global_planner.I don't want to use waypoint_maker

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372705/autoware-open-planner/) by [liuliuliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70833/liuliuliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't do that with only point cloud, you need to create a Road Network map on top of the point cloud.
for op_global_planner to work, you need either vector map or km map.

To create vector map you can use [TierIV tools](https://tools.tier4.jp/)

To create KML map you can use [ASSURE](https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/assuremappingtools) mapping tool.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2021-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuliuliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70833/liuliuliu/) on 2021-03-28**:
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I have another question，Can obstacle avoidance function be realized in tracking mode？Don't use op_ global_ planner.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2021-03-29**:
Please only ask one question per post. This helps others find answers.